# Custom Work Item Type: Adding Unique ID Constraint

Tags: azure-devops

I created a custom work item type (WIT) and I added a field of type integer for usage as unique identifier.  It is called **ID** and is a required field.

I would like the following constraint:

When a user creates a new work item of this type and inserts a value for **ID**, a check is run to verify that there is no work item of this type that already has the same **ID**.  If so the user should be prevented from creating the work item.

The point is to avoid having multiple work items of this type with duplicate unique IDs.  I looked into the "Rules" section to see if I could add a constraint to check for pre-existing integers of the same value, and prevent the user from creating the WIT if it already exists in the system.  However I was not able to find a way to do so.  I also tried making the field of type identifier but that just forces you to user a person (not number) as an identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goals are not clear in your question. You already have ID (or `System.Id` as system reference) for each work item type. You do not need to create something new. Rules in work items types do not support complex logic ([Sample custom rule scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/rule-samples?view=azure-devops&tabs=inheritance)).

As a workaround (if you need the second id for your work item type), you can:

1. Set default value 0 for your field.
2. Create a custom app to:

   1. Find 0 ids: [Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).
   2. Updated them to the calculated value: [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

Comment: I re-edited my post.  I hope it explains things better.

Comment: @Arkatakor, in your case there is no out-of-box solution. Here you can develop your own extension (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension?view=azure-devops) or custom app as I mentioned.

Comment: Ok, so whats the protocol in such a situation?  Do I accept your answer?

Comment: @Arkatakor, up to you. If you decide to do something based on the answer - yes.

Comment: I wont be developing an extension just for this, however I would suggest you post that suggestion in your original answer as I will now approve it.